# Laravel: How do I get the ID of the model attached to the model being used

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So, I have this line of code in my controller

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
```

this is on my `AppUser.php` model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
}
```

when I try to do this:

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->user()->pluck('uuid');
```

It returns the uuid of the AppUser. What I want is to get the UUID of the user. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this `$user = Auth::guard('api')->user->pluck('uuid');`

Comment: @GabMic it says `"Cannot access protected property Tymon\\JWTAuth\\JWTGuard::$user"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked: (hahaha) I shouldn't have included plucked.

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
$user_id = $user->uuid;
```

and it gets the UUID of the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have AppUser registered as the user model in your authentication config, then Auth::user() will return an instance of AppUser.

Once you have AppUser, you can use the user() relationship as a property to access the related model's properties.

```
$appUserModel = Auth::guard('api')->user();
$userModel = $appUserModel->user;
$uuid = $userModel->uuid;
// or as one line:
$uuid = Auth::guard('api')->user()->user->uuid;
```

Comment: It says `"Trying to get property of non-object"` and is pointing to my `return $uuid`

Comment: Seems like your user relationship is set up incorrectly or you don't have a related user for this AppUser instance then..

Comment: my `User.php`'s connection to AppUser is like this: `return $this->hasMany('App\Models\AppUser', 'user_id');`

Comment: According to your question details, you're not using that relationship, you'd be using the AppUser model's user relationship.   I think you need to debug the AppUser instance to make sure this relationship is working as expected.